# Getting IDs and values of dynamically created text boxes on Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a web application asp.net.

I am creating 54 text boxes dynamically in Page_Load

Here is the code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(i = 0, i<54, i++)
    {
        Textbox TestTextbox = new texbox();
        TestTextBox.ID = "Reg" + i ;
        TestTextBox.Attributes.add("runat","server");
        TestTextBoxAttributes.Add("AutoPostBack", "true");

        //display to a table called table1 created in the aspx page
    }
}
```

On the page I have a button, called button1, and a on click event called "OnClickEvent", i want to capture the ID and the values of all the textboxes.

I have used Page.Controls.Count and I get only 1, the table that I have added to the aspx page, I get the IDs by using Request.Form but I`m not getting the values.

I am adding all the text boxes to a Table that I have created in the aspx file.

Comment: Did you try using Control.FindControl("") ?

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel did you mean to say page.findcontrol?

Comment: You can try (just for testing puposes) var x = Page.FindControl("Reg20"); If that works, You just look 54 times and get the controls and their values.

Comment: Yep it works, but isn`t there a way to get all the controls of a certain type ? and loop through them after

Comment: Not to my knowledge. foreach(Control c in Page.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        // Do whatever you want to do with your textbox.
    }
} is the closest to what you are suggesting.

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel can you please post your answer so I can mark it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the controls and check if they are of type TextBox:

```
for(int i = 0, i<54, i++)) { 
    var control = Page.FindControl("Reg" + i);
    //get the value of the control 
}
```

Comment: nope, :d the other one with find controls, it`s the only way to skip the endless looping

Comment: I changed the solution.

Comment: the main idea is that the if you have multiple layers of controls you need to go through them, my solution was to store the ids in a list and on button click to through the list with page.findcontrol(id)

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the TextBox to the Page, so you cannot find it anyway. Second, adding `runat=server` and `AutoPostBack=true` as a string would not work either. (not to mention your snippet is full of errors)

```
//a loop uses ';', not ','
for (int i = 0; i < 54; i++)
{
    //declare a new dynamic textbox = CaSe SeNsItIvE
    TextBox TestTextbox = new TextBox();
    TestTextbox.ID = "Reg" + i;

    //if you want to add attibutes you do it like this
    TestTextbox.AutoPostBack = true;
    TestTextbox.TextChanged += TestTextbox_TextChanged;

    //add the textbox to the page
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(TestTextbox);
}
```

And if you want to loop all the controls you can do something like this

```
//loop all the controls that were added to the placeholder
foreach (Control control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
{
    //is it a textbox
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        //cast the control back to a textbox to access it's properties
        TextBox tb = control as TextBox;
        string id = tb.ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your remarks, but this doesn`t work if you have a multi level situation, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4.aspx

Comment: Then you have to make the method recursive. There are examples here on SO. But not recommended since they are very slow.